Plot an infinite but convergent series
I would like to plot the following function
$$
 f(m)=-2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{k} \left(2^{2(k-1)}-1\right)\zeta(2 (k-1))\left(m^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)^k
$$
I am only interested in $m$ between 0 and 1. I can't plot it with infinity as an upper bound; it appears as an error message:

This computation has exceeded the time limit for your plan.

So I must truncate it. Would there be a way to plot the entire function?
Because then my function is not what I expect and I guess it is a consequence of not considering all the terms.
Here is my simple code for that:
Plot[-2Sum[Binomial[1/2, n](2^(2(n-1))-1) Zeta[2(n-1)] (m^2-1/4)^n, 
  {n, 0, 200}], {m, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.2}]


This is a tricky sum because for $m>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ we need analytic continuation or regularization to compute it.
A simplified version of the sum approximates $\zeta[2(k-1)]\approx 1$ and
$$
f(m)=-2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{k}\left(2^{2(k-1)}-1\right)\zeta\left[2(k-1)\right]\left(m^2-\frac14\right)^k\\
\approx-2\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{k}\left(2^{2(k-1)}-1\right)\left(m^2-\frac14\right)^k\\
= \sqrt{4 m^2+3}-m-\frac{3}{2}.
$$
The last step is only strictly correct when the exponential term is smaller than 1 in magnitude: $\left(2^{2k-1}-1\right)\left(m^2-\frac14\right)^k\approx\frac12\left(4m^2-1\right)^k$ and the sum only converges if $\left|4m^2-1\right|\le1$, meaning $|m|\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. For larger $m$ the sum converges only after regularization.
You can see the effect of this in @UlrichNeumann's solution: for $m>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ explicit summing no longer works, and regularization is required.
However, I don't know how to use regularization in a numerical sum. Better ask at the math StackExchange.
update: numerical summing that works
Expand the Riemann ζ-function by its definition: $\zeta[2(n-1)]=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2(n-1)}}$, from which
$$
f(m)=-2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{n}\left(2^{2(n-1)}-1\right)\zeta\left[2(n-1)\right]\left(m^2-\frac14\right)^n\\
=-2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{n}\left(2^{2(n-1)}-1\right)\left(m^2-\frac14\right)^n\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2(n-1)}}
$$
(the lower limit on $n$ can be set to 2 because for $n=0$ and $n=1$ the summand is zero).
Interchange the order of summation: (this is the "renormalization step" that maybe some mathematicians will take issue with; but it works in practice)
$$
f(m)=-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{n}\left(2^{2(n-1)}-1\right)\left(m^2-\frac14\right)^n\frac{1}{k^{2(n-1)}}
$$
Now we can do the $n$-summation exactly:
f[m_, n_, k_] = -2 (-1 + 2^(2 (-1 + n))) (-(1/4) + m^2)^n Binomial[1/2, n] 1/k^(2 (n - 1));
f[m_, k_] = Assuming[0 < m < 1 && Element[k, PositiveIntegers], 
    Sum[f[m, n, k], {n, 2, ∞}] // FullSimplify]
(*    -(1/2) k (3 k + Sqrt[-1 + k^2 + 4 m^2] - 2 Sqrt[-1 + 4 k^2 + 4 m^2])    *)

This formulation is no longer divergent and can be summed numerically for any $m$:
f[m_] = Sum[f[m, k], {k, 1, 10^3}] // Expand;
Plot[f[m], {m, 0, 1}]


If you need more accuracy in the sum, I'd suggest using an asymptotic expansion of the summand for large $k$ and then summing that all the way to infinity:
f∞[m_, k_] = Series[f[m, k], {k, ∞, 10}] // Normal

$$
\frac{3 \left(4 m^2-1\right)^2}{64 k^2}
-\frac{15\left(4 m^2-1\right)^3}{512 k^4}
+\frac{315 \left(4 m^2-1\right)^4}{16384 k^6}
-\frac{1785 \left(4 m^2-1\right)^5}{131072 k^8}
+\frac{21483 \left(4 m^2-1\right)^6}{2097152 k^{10}}
$$
With[{kmax = 10^3},
  f[m_] = Sum[f[m, k], {k, 1, kmax}] +
          Sum[f∞[m, k], {k, kmax + 1, ∞}] // Expand];

f[1/Sqrt[2]] // N
(*    0.057067155838012695    *)


In 14.1 on Windows Simplify[(Series[      Binomial[1/2, n] (2^(2 (n - 1)) - 1) Zeta[2 (n - 1)] (m^2 - 1/4)^        n, {n, Infinity, 1}] // Normal) /. Arg[-(1/2) + n] -> 0] results in  $\frac{\left(4^n-4\right) e^{\frac{11}{24 n}} \left(m^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n \cos (\pi  n)}{8 \sqrt{\pi } n^{3/2}}$, confiming the condition on $m$.

@Roman SumConvergence[] confirms your expectation m<Sqrt[2], see my modified answer!

@UlrichNeumann: Abs[1/4 - m^2] < 1 && Abs[1 - 4 m^2] < 1 only partly confirms it, not including 0 and 1/Sqrt[2] and -1/Sqrt[2].

@user64494 No that isn't correct! Try Plot[Abs[1 - 4 m^2], {m, 0, 1},   RegionFunction -> Function[m, Abs[1 - 4 m^2] < 1]]

@UlrichNeumann: Substitute m==0/m==1/Sqrt[2]/-1/Sqrt[2]  in Abs[1/4 - m^2] < 1 && Abs[1 - 4 m^2] < 1 or /and look at the result of Reduce[Abs[1/4 - m^2] < 1 && Abs[1 - 4 m^2] < 1,m,Reals].

@Roman: "For larger m the sum converges only after regularization" are empty words. Neither Regularization->"Borel" nor Regularization->"Dirichlet" works in 14.1 on Windows even for m==1.

@user64494 I think my recommended Plot shows the whole story 0<m<1/Sqrt[2]

@Roman Interesting update! Does this result mean that the convergence estimate SumConvergence[] is wrong?

@UlrichNeumann the convergence estimate refers to a specific formulation, not the analytic continuation. Simpler example: Sum[x^n, {n, ∞}] gives $\frac{x}{1-x}$, which can be evaluated for any $x\in\mathbb{C}$. But SumConvergence[x^n, n] gives Abs[x] < 1. So the SumConvergence refers only to the specific sum given, not to the general analytic continuation (which can be expressed in many ways, some of which converge and some of which don't). For example, for $x=2$ we can evaluate $\frac{x}{1-x}=-2$ but we cannot evaluate the sum directly and the partial sums diverge.

@Roman Thank you very much, learned something new

Using: $$\zeta (n)=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{-1+n}}{\left(-1+e^x\right) \Gamma (n)} \, dx$$
then:
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } -2 \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n} \left(2^{2 (n-1)}-1\right) \zeta (2 (n-1)) \left(m^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n=\\\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } -2 \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n} \left(2^{2 (n-1)}-1\right) \int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{-1+2
   (-1+n)} \left(m^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n}{\left(-1+e^x\right) \Gamma (2 (-1+n))} \, dx=\\\int_0^{\infty } \left(\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } -\frac{2 \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n} \left(2^{2 (n-1)}-1\right) x^{-1+2 (-1+n)}
   \left(m^2-\frac{1}{4}\right)^n}{\left(-1+e^x\right) \Gamma (2 (-1+n))}\right) \, dx=\\\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\left(-1+4 m^2\right) \left(I_2\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-4 m^2} x\right)-I_2\left(\sqrt{1-4 m^2} x\right)\right)}{2
   \left(-1+e^x\right) x} \, dx$$
f[m_?NumericQ] := -2 Sum[Binomial[1/2, n] (2^(2 (n - 1)) - 1) Zeta[2 (n - 1)] (m^2 - 1/4)^n, {n, 0, 200}]; 
f1[m_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[((-1 + 4 m^2) (BesselI[2, 1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 m^2] x] - BesselI[2, Sqrt[1 - 4 m^2] x]))/(2 (-1 + E^x) x), {x, 0, Infinity}] // Quiet
g[m_] = Sum[-(1/2) k (3 k + Sqrt[-1 + k^2 + 4 m^2] - 2 Sqrt[-1 + 4 k^2 + 4 m^2]), {k, 1, 10^2}];

Plot[{f[m], f1[m], g[m], Sqrt[4 m^2 + 3] - m - 3/2}, {m, 0, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {0, 0.3}, 
PlotLabels -> {"Ulrich Neumann solution", "My solution", 
"Roman Updated solution", "Roman approximate solution"}, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Black}, {DotDashed, Blue}, Green}]


Addendum:
 $Version
 (*"14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"*)

 Sum[-2 Binomial[1/2, n] (2^(2 (n - 1)) - 1)*
 x^(-1 + 2 (-1 + n))/((-1 + E^x) Gamma[2 (-1 + n)])*(m^2 - 1/4)^
 n, {n, 0, Infinity}]

 (*((-1 + 4 m^2) (BesselI[2, 1/2 Sqrt[1 - 4 m^2] x] + 
 BesselJ[2, Sqrt[-1 + 2 m] Sqrt[1 + 2 m] x]))/(2 (-1 + E^x) x)*)


Interesting solution (+1) ! Have concerns about swapping the order of summation and integration, it is probably only permissible if the sum is convergent!

How did you find the sum-formula in your last Latex-line? Mathematica v12.2 doesn't evaluate!

@UlrichNeumann For second question see my updated. For first  question wrong address. Your question is pure math. Ask that in math forums. Is this about Wolfram Mathematica or a math question? :P

Thanks!: I am also not a mathematician, only foggy memories let me to this first statement. By the way that might be the "proof" why our two solutions  match in the convergence area!

To address the time issue, evaluate the sum once. Plot is reevaluating it at each point it plots.
poly = HornerForm[-2 Sum[
     Binomial[1/2, n] (2^(2 (n - 1)) - 1) Zeta[2 (n - 1)] x^n, {n, 0, 
      200}]];
Plot[
 Block[{x}, x = m^2 - 1/4; poly],
 {m, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0., 0.2}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02]]

Of course, you may prefer the mathematically complete solutions given in other answers. But the answer to the time problem you're facing in the cloud should be handled by the approach above and be useful knowledge to have about using Wolfram tech. Especially if one is interested in exploring the partial sums.

Four times faster than my answer (0.016s vs. 0.065s): coeff = -2 Table[Binomial[1/2, n] (2^(2 (n - 1)) - 1) Zeta[2 (n - 1)], {n, 0, 200}] // N; Plot[Block[{x}, x = (m^2 - 0.25)^Range[0., 200.]; coeff . x],  {m, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0., 0.2}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02]]

modified
Try
f[m_?NumericQ] := -2 Sum[
   Binomial[1/2, n] (2^(2 (n - 1)) - 1) Zeta[2 (n - 1)] (m^2 - 1/4)^
     n, {n, 0, 200}]
Plot[f[m], {m, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.2}]


addendum
Inspired by @Roman's comment we get
cond=SumConvergence[-2 Binomial[1/2, n] (2^(2 (n - 1)) - 1) Zeta[2 (n - 1)] (m^2 - 1/4)^n, n]
(*Abs[1/4 - m^2] < 1 && Abs[1 - 4 m^2] < 1*)

Reduce[RealAbs[1/4 - m^2] < 1 && RealAbs[1 - 4 m^2] < 1 && 0 < m <1]
 (*0 < m < 1/Sqrt[2]*)

in accordance with the plot

Right, this is what I got, but around 0.7 it is strange. I was expecting something more or less quadratic.

Unfortunately, Abs[1/4 - m^2] < 1 && Abs[1 - 4 m^2] < 1 does not include m==0 and m==1/Sqrt[2] and m==-1/Sqrt[2] where the series converges (see my comment to the @Roman's answer).

@user64494 No that isn't correct! Try Plot[Abs[1 - 4 m^2], {m, 0, 1},   RegionFunction -> Function[m, Abs[1 - 4 m^2] < 1]]

Substitute m==0/m==1/Sqrt[2]/-1/Sqrt[2]  in Abs[1/4 - m^2] < 1 && Abs[1 - 4 m^2] < 1 or /and look at the result of Reduce[Abs[1/4 - m^2] < 1 && Abs[1 - 4 m^2] < 1,m,Reals].

@user64494 Reduce gives incorrect result in v12.2, change Abs to RealAbs (see my answer)

You are not right: Reduce[RealAbs[1/4 - m^2] < 1 && RealAbs[1 - 4 m^2] < 1, m, Reals] performs the same -(1/Sqrt[2])<m<0||0<m<1/Sqrt[2]. Also look at the result of Plot[f[m], {m, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}] in your notations. Aren't you tired?

@user64494 Is 0<m<1/Sqrt[2] not the result convergence radius we are talking about. I'm out of this unsuccessfull discussion
